# Grub rescue "symbol not found: ‘grub_efi_secure_boot'", cannot fix 'unknown file system' error

Tags: dual-boot, grub, elementary-os

This is on a Lenovo Thinkpad 13. It dual-boots Windows 10 and Elementary OS with the grub boot manager. It's UEFI.

Upon booting, I received the "error: unknown filesystem" message

Commands:

```
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub/  
grub rescue> insmod linux  
error: symbol 'grub_efi_secure_boot' not found.
```

Alternatively, when I was trying a different approach:

```
grub rescue> set root=(hd0,5)  
grub rescue> set prefix=(hd0,5)/boot/grub  
grub rescue> insmod normal  
grub rescue> normal
```

However, when selecting Elementary OS, I was met with:

```
error: symbol 'grub_efi_secure_boot' not found.
```

I'm pretty sure that (hd0,5) is the correct one, though, as it does not give the unknown file system error and the .mod files are there.

Additional/Full context, including potentially useful/crucial bits of info:

I had initially set up this laptop to dual boot Windows 10 and Arch Linux.
Due to some issues with grub not appearing, I had entered `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\arch\grubx64.efi` into the Windows administrative command prompt to make this work.
Eventually, I decided that Arch wasn't right for me and switched to Elementary OS.
I deleted the Arch partitions through Windows, and then installed Elementary OS. I then successfully booted into Elementary and installed some software.
Afterwards, I booted into Windows to do some minor things such as set wallpaper and the like.
After rebooting the computer, I was met with grub rescue, and the above situation has occurred.

Edit: Secure boot is disabled

Comment: Is secure boot disabled?

Comment: Yeah, it's disabled